# Compare x and y coordinates to values in a dictionary and categorize values using keys in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

So my goal is to take a csv data file and compare the x and y values (in separate columns) to values in a dictionary and then categorize the x and y coordinates based on the key of the said dictionary.

This is the code for my dictionary:

```
def aoi_dict():
# NOTE : this needs to be changed.
aoi = {'Reels': [(77, 0), (946, 446)],  # Reels
       'Credits': [(484, 447), (669, 520)],  # Credits
       'Win': [(670, 447), (893, 520)],  # Wins
       'Others_tl': [(0, 0), (76, 520)],  # Uncategorized top left window
       'Others_bl': [(77, 447), (483, 520)],  # Uncategorized bottom left window
       'Others_br': [(894, 447), (946, 520)],  # Uncategorized bottom right window
       'Others_tr': [(947, 0), (1024, 520)]}  # Uncategorized top right window
return aoi
```

This is the code to categorize the data in the file:

```
def add_durations():

fixations = select_fixations_data().groupby(by=['fixation_id', 'duration'])[['x_scaled',
                                                                             'y_scaled']].mean().reset_index()
cdict = d_aoi.aoi_dict()

x = fixations["x_scaled"]
y = fixations["y_scaled"]

for i, pt in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    if ((pt[0] > cdict['Reels'][0][0]) and (pt[1] > cdict['Reels'][0][1])
            and (pt[0] < cdict['Reels'][1][0]) and (pt[1] < cdict['Reels'][1][1])):
        fixations['Category'] = list(cdict.keys())[0]

    if ((pt[0] > cdict['Credits'][0][0]) and (pt[1] > cdict['Credits'][0][1])
            and (pt[0] < cdict['Credits'][1][0]) and (pt[1] < cdict['Credits'][1][1])):
        fixations['Category'] = list(cdict.keys())[1]

    if ((pt[0] > cdict['Win'][0][0]) and (pt[1] > cdict['Win'][0][1])
            and (pt[0] < cdict['Win'][1][0]) and (pt[1] < cdict['Win'][1][1])):
        fixations['Category'] = list(cdict.keys())[2]

fixations.to_csv('/home/fiza/Documents/ClarkLabProjects/SF_Immersion_Data/fixdurations.csv', index=False)
```

I am getting the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Additionally, I want to re-name the remaining coordinates as Uncategorized (which would be Others_tl, Others_bl, Others_br or Others_tr). But, I am not sure how to get to this point!

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

That error is probably coming from lines like this one:

```
  if fixations[(fixations['x_scaled'].between(aoi['Reels'][0][0], aoi['Reels'][1][0], inclusive=True)) &
             (fixations['y_scaled'].between(aoi['Reels'][0][1], aoi['Reels'][1][1], inclusive=True))].all():
```

The `all()` result in that expression is not a `bool`.  It is a `Series`.  That's because the input is a `DataFrame` and `all()` will use `axis=0` by default. (That's unlike `np.all()`, which operates on all axes by default.)

To use that condition in an `if` statement, you need to further reduce it to a `bool`.  I don't know what you want to do, so I can't say exactly what the answer is.  One option is to use `.all().all()`, which checks if EVERY entry in the whole `DataFrame` is `True`.  Another option is to select a specific column of the result, and then call `.all()` on only that `Series`.

Comment: It's still giving me the same error. I am comparing values in the dictionary to values in the excel sheet and assigning appropriate keys accordingly.